# Forcing SSH login on Ubuntu 14.04 server not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, login, rsa

I've tried enabling SSH logins in my linux server. It can establish connection just fine trough my private key. I also went to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and edited the following field like this:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

But it still lets me login trough a username/password when I use putty or winSCP. Right now I can login both from user/password and SSH keys, which is rather pointless as far as security goes. What else do I need to do to ONLY allow SSH logins?

Comment: You are editing the wrong file. SSH server config is under `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: ah yes, my bad. I also had to change these 2 options: PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no and restart the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify different file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and you need to disable also `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` like this:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

and restart the service.